# Crashlytics: Cannot Find Project When Adding New App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

The Crashlytics plug-in has installed correctly and I have been using it successfully in a separate project but when I click +New App in the drop down my new project does not show up. Although, it does show all of the libraries I am using in my project, just not the project itself. Any ideas?

I've tried googling but I can't seem to find any relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can add it manually, then if you restart the plug-in (ctrl+l) and log back in it works.